# C - Writing duplicate array records into a text file

Tags: c, arrays, file

> In this C program i have an array with duplicate student IDs. When I try to 
>       write it to a text file, it skips the duplicate values and write the 
>       remaining data into the file with value 0 in each duplicated value. But I 
>       want to write that duplicate record also into the file.
>
> Here's my code;

```
int WriteData(struct Sales StoreSales[])
{
 int i;
 FILE *fptr;

 fptr = fopen("reverseOrder.txt", "w");

 if(fptr == NULL)
 {
   printf("\nError: File cannot be opened\n");
   return -1;
 }

 fprintf(fptr, "\nStudent ID\tSales Amount\n");

 for(i = SIZE ; i > 0 ; i--)
 {
   fprintf(fptr, "%d\t\t\t%d\n", StoreSales[i].StudentID, 
   StoreSales[i].amount );
 }

 fclose(fptr);
 }

 Here's my array;

 301 -> 4
 201 -> 3
 657 -> 4
 234 -> 9
 301 -> 8
 201 -> 4
```

> As I'm a beginner to C, I can't find out a way to solve this issue. Any 
>        helpful ideas to fix my code? Thank You!

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: i want to write the given array in the reverse order with all the duplicate values. @coderredoc

Comment: Can you show the output which you got?

Comment: 201 -> 4
301 -> 8
234 -> 9
657 -> 4
0 -> 0
0 -> 0

@Karthick

Comment: Please post the whole program.

Comment: There are bunch of different methods which i have done some calculations. But i hope you are asking me the main and the structure right? @Karthick

Comment: Yes. Which I can compile and execute. @hashini.W

Comment: the posted code does not even come close to compiling.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Strongly suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: when calling: `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "your error message" );` followed by a call to `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  I.E. output the error message to `stderr`, not `stdout`

Comment: regarding: `for(i = SIZE ; i > 0 ; i--)`   in C, array indexs start with 0 and continue to (number of elements in array -1).  So in the current scenario, the first access will be beyond the end of the array and the first element of the array will never be accessed.

Comment: the variable `size` is not defined within the posted code.  Perhaps you should use: `sizeof( StoreSales ) / sizeof( StoreSales[0] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having undefined behavior accessing array index out of bound.

```
for(i = SIZE ; i > 0 ; i--)
```

will be

```
for(i = SIZE-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
```

In C, array indexing starts from `0`. You have the array of structures with `SIZE` number of elements which can be accessed using indices `0,1,...SIZE-1`. [0-indexing]. When you accessed the element having index `SIZE` you have accessed memory out of the array which you are not permitted to - resulting in undefined behavior.

#### Further explanation:

You might access some memory that is not owned by your program which will make your program crash (accessing memory that your program is not supposed to). Or this might change some part of memory owned by your program giving rise to Erroneous results.( If read only then it will gives rise to error).

Comment: OMG Great! It Worked! Thank You @coderredoc! :) But i would be glad enough if you could explain this issue further!

Comment: @hashini.W.: Explained

Comment: @hashini.W.: No need to be sorry. It's ok. I thought there might be some issue. Be cool.

Comment: No issues my code worked fine with the help of your answer and it left me to think twice before handling arrays :)

Comment: @hashini.W: That's great. All the best.